# How to secure AES keys in android

Tags: android, security, encryption, aes

I'm creating payment library andi need to save **2 AES key**, the **AES keys are private** and **user must not access them**
now i save them in `sharedPrefrences`, **and my question is**
**is there another way for secure my keys?**

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: May be your approach is just the problem. A payment library usually should not use symmetric encryption like AES but asymmetric encryption like RSA or ECDSA. Then key privacy of the public key is not that of a problem if your encryption scheme has been designed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly discourage you storing SecretKeys in SharedPreferneces.

Have a look at [AndroidKeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) to save it in a secure manner.

Also Note that a root user might be able to hook onto your app encryption method and may be able to break it that way.

Comment: thanks,
but i need `AES keys` for `every transaction`, because of this i think i need to save generated key for `encrypt/decrypt` my `AES keys`, so how can i save the generated keys ?

Comment: You haven't even read the link I posted, have you? It cleary states how to store AES keys in the built-in `AndroidKeyStore`. For a more detailed explanation which comes along with sample code visit https://medium.com/@josiassena/using-the-android-keystore-system-to-store-sensitive-information-3a56175a454b

Comment: I think OP is looking for a DRM solution. Even if the keys are stored in the Android Key Store they can still be used by the user.

Comment: @JamesKPolk You mean, as in *any* data on a rooted user device can be tampered with?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. The Android Keystore may be supported by tamper-resistant hardware, so tamper is not the right word. But the keys present therein can always be used for the purposes they were created with, with or without the app that created them.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Really? They can be used without the app?? The docs state "Use the Android Keystore provider to let an individual app store its own credentials that only the app itself can access." https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#WhichShouldIUse Are you shure you didn't confuse this with the `KeyChain` API?